# Copy Fields From One Table to Another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looping through a set of values `$id` and on certain occasions I need to copy 2 fields of data from one table (product) to another (product_new). Both tables already exist and both contain identical fields 'product_description' and 'image'. I am trying to do this with:

```
$copy_query = "SELECT product_description, image INTO product_new FROM product WHERE product_id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($copy_query) or die('Could not copy the database data: ' . mysql_error() .  '<br>Query: ' . $copy_query);
```

The error is 'Undeclared variable: product_new'. I don't understand this though because I perform other operations with table product_new without issue. Any thoughts? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the link to the differences doc. That definitely helped, however I have one more issue. My current query is:

```
$copy_query = "INSERT INTO product_new (product_description, image)
    SELECT product.product_description, product.image
    FROM product
    WHERE product_id=$id";
```

but this is writing the data to a new row with product_id = 0. I need it to write to the row with product_id = $id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support the `SELECT INTO` syntax.

Also, it's generally very inefficient to run queries inside of a loop. Instead, you can make a comma separated list of the `id`s in PHP and use:

```
$copy_query = '
    INSERT INTO product_new (product_description, image)
    SELECT product_description, image
    FROM   product
    WHERE  product_id IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';

mysql_query($copy_query);
```

Where `$ids` is the array of your ids.

This solution needs only to be executed once (rather than many times within a loop).

---

**EDIT**: If you already have rows that exist in `product_new` and you want to update them, you can use:

```
$copy_query = '
    UPDATE product_new a
    JOIN   product b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
                    AND b.product_id IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')
    SET    a.product_description = b.product_description,
           a.image = b.image';

mysql_query($copy_query);
```

Comment: Nice! I just had to add the word INNER in front of JOIN. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Glad it works, but I don't see how adding `INNER` would make the query run differently. `INNER` is optional and implied when it's just `JOIN`...

Answer (score 4):

The reason is because MySQL doesn't support `SELECT...INTO` queries.

Instead use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` to achieve the same result.

See [SELECT INTO Table Differences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) on the reference manual for more information.

Comment: Thanks. That link was helpful. Is there a way to copy these fields to an existing row in product_new with product_id=$id?